# ImportError: No module named msg

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have to msg files in a msg folder. Added both msg to the CMakeList.txt and followed the instructions in the file, so the package.xml has the right dependencies. I also followed these answers on this similar questions: https://answers.ros.org/question/105711/rospy-custom-message-importerror-no-module-named-msg/ and https://answers.ros.org/question/271620/importerror-no-module-named-xxxxmsg/

But i still get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/pozyx_ros_examples/src/pozyx_node.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pozyx_ros_examples.msg import DeviceRange, EulerAngles
ImportError: No module named msg
```

My package.xml and CMakeLists.txt are in gist: https://gist.github.com/kwint/09ab135968f83d06fae7f0af0fe835a2

I'm running lubuntu 16.04 on a raspberry pi.

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── __init__.py
├── msg
│   ├── DeviceRange.msg
│   ├── EulerAngles.msg
│   └── __init__.py
├── package.xml
└── src
    ├── pozyx_node.py
    └── setup_nodes
        └── pozyx_configuration.py
```

The weird thing is that when I run this package on my local computer it works perfectly (which runs ubuntu 16.04)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287744/importerror:-no-module-named-msg/) by [kwint](https://answers.ros.org/users/34217/kwint/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2018-04-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-04-06**:
did you compile the package with `catkin_make`? This is required to generate the respective python modules/C++ headers...

**Comment by [kwint](https://answers.ros.org/users/34217/kwint/) on 2018-04-06**:
Yes I have, also source the setup.bash file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you put the `__init__.py` in the `msg` sub dir? If so: remove it, remove your `build` and `devel` folder, rebuild your workspace and see whether things start working.

---

Edit:

> That might have been the solution, **init**.py was empty. But I make a completely new ros module and just copied the msg files and scripts to it, now it works. I have know idea why exactly, but ok

You should not place any `__init__.py` files anywhere except when you're creating Python *modules*. ROS msgs (so the `.msg` files) are not modules. The code generated *from them* becomes a module, but that is all done automatically for you.

The `__init__.py` in your package root and the `msg` subdir should not be there. Only if you're creating a Python module, you place one in the subdir that stores the sources for your module.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwint](https://answers.ros.org/users/34217/kwint/) on 2018-04-06**:
That might have been the solution, **init**.py was empty. But I make a completely new ros module and just copied the msg files and scripts to it, now it works. I have know idea why exactly, but ok